# How can i reduce the Facebook permissions to minimum required

Tags: facebook

For example my web site name is "DOMINOS". I have a DOMINOS facebook APP called DOMINOS.FB.APP (App name)

If user is not added under DOMINOS.FB.APP, it show one page when user try to login with facebook. (User will be added only once)

In that pop-up facebook show ,

```
DOMINOS is requesting permission to do the following:

Access my basic information
Includes name, profile picture, gender, networks, user ID, list of friends, and any other information I've shared with everyone.

Send me email
Dev.SJ may email me directly at sahal006@gmail.com · 

.......
..... 
etc etc
```

I don't want above pop up to be displayed Or i can control the permission somewhere in the APP account ?

Comment: What language are you using? php,JS,python...? from there check if you are adding a `perms` or `scope` parameter. Obviously you are asking for the `email` permission.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I think you are saying about Facebook login button (`<fb:login-button>` tag). If that is the case, you should find an attribute "perms" that is set "email" **on your HTML page** (where user click to login with Facebook), not in the FB app settings.